# Mantel's Theorem on $G(n,p)$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, probabilistic-method

I want to prove the following theorem:

> With high probability, every subgraph $G\subset G(n,1/2)$ with
>   $$e(G)\geq \left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)\frac{n^2}{4}$$
>   contains a triangle.

I think this the usual probabilistic method (proving that $\mathbb{P}(G \text{ is triangle-free})\to 0$) works here. However I don't quite understand how to do this since the variable that tends to infinity is not the number of vertices of $G$, but only the number of vertices of $G(n,1/2)$.

Would the expected number of triangles in $G$ be
$$\frac{1}{2^3}\binom{v(G)}{3}?$$
It is not obvious to me which properties $G$ inherits of $G(n,1/2)$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems like you could assume that $G$ is spanning. Does that help?

Comment: @BobKrueger, that implies that my $\frac{1}{2^3}\binom{v(G)}{3}$ is right. But it does not solve the problem. Why could I assume that $G$ is spanning?